# How to differentiate between rotated character or a number from a simple line with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, bounding-box

At the moment I am trying to get an idea how to distinguish a character or a number from a simple line. This way I'm trying to filter irrelevant input for Tesseract OCR. My idea is to use `connectedComponentsWithStats` to get the minimum box around my components and then check how many white or black pixels are in a given bounding box. By setting a BW ratio, I want to find the filled boxes that are the lines I want to filter.

The input I have is a lot of images that only have a letter/character or line rotated on them. I can rotate them by the minimum rectangle but unfortunately I can't crop them. Do you have any hints or maybe a better idea to check the BW ratio in my rotated box?

[Rotated component Character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwojD.png)

[more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKQiA.png)

```
    analysis_of_single_groups = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(rotated_without_box, 4, cv2.CV_32S)
    (totalLabels_s_g, label_ids_s_g, values_s_g, centroid_s_g) = analysis_of_single_groups

    for i in range(1, totalLabels_s_g):
        x = values_s_g[i, cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]
        y = values_s_g[i, cv2.CC_STAT_TOP]
        w = values_s_g[i, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]
        h = values_s_g[i, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]

    print("x: " + str(x))


    crop_img = rotated_without_box[y:y + h, x:x + w].copy()
    cv2.imwrite("ta/cropped_" + str(i) + ".png", crop_img)

    number_of_white_pix = np.sum(crop_img == 0)  # extracting only white pixels
    number_of_black_pix = np.sum(crop_img == 255)  # extracting only black pixels
    bw_ratio = number_of_white_pix / number_of_black_pix
    bw_ratio < 0.9
```

Comment: Not quite clear what you want to do. But what about trying OCR on a region of interest, rotated four ways and keeping the best read ?

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.findContours` -> filter contours by hierarchy -> filter by HW ratio

[image: in]
[image: out]

Image 2:
[image: out2]

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

gray = cv2.imread("/Users/alex/Downloads/dwojD_2.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(image=thresh, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
hierarchy = hierarchy[0]

bgr = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
for i in range(len(hierarchy)):
    if hierarchy[i][3] >= 0: 
        continue # ignore, some parents are here
    
    rRect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[i])
    size = rRect[1]
    if min(size) == 0: 
        continue
    ratio = max(size) / min(size)
    print("Min rect size", size, "; Ratio", ratio)

    # you can filter contours by width and height ratio
    isSymbol = ratio < 3
    color = (0, 255, 0) if isSymbol else (0, 0, 255)

    if isSymbol: print("> Symbol!")
    else: print("> Line!")

    
    # cv2.drawContours(image=bgr, contours=contours, contourIdx=i, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    box = np.int0(cv2.boxPoints(rRect))
    cv2.drawContours(image=bgr, contours=[box], contourIdx=0, color=color, thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    

cv2.imshow("img", bgr)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: i tried this, but it does not work if the line is smaller ... and there is also the risk to telete 1s

Comment: You can customize ratio threshold youself. And if it not work, please provide image. On your image only symbol `A` is appear.

Comment: I have provided another image. My plans are to delete the (sometimes slightly curved) lines

Comment: Just change ratio to 3. I've attach processed image